# Compose Desktop is based on AWT, is it a permanent decision?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jetbrains-compose

I have a Swing component that I'd like to re-implement from scratch using Compose. What I've found, is that many of the Compose features just wrap AWT. For example, `PointerEvent` class has a `nativeEvent` which is an instance of `java.awt.event.MouseEvent.`

Is it safe to rely on these AWT types? Will Compose eventually replace them or not?

Comment: Such questions are best addressed directly to the [maintainers](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb)

Comment: They didn't reply there either :)